# Converting jQuery .map() method call to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript2.0

I am refactoring some .js files to Typescript.

Referencing https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/types-2.0/jquery to resolve jQuery methods.

The source code has several instances of code similar to this:

```
$("#id").map( (ev)=> {
  return $(ev.target).val();
})
```

The usage suggests that map takes a callback, with `ev` an event (with a target property), however jQuery.d.ts defines the method as follows:

```
map(callback: (index: number, domElement: Element) => any): JQuery;
```

As a result the Typescript compiler barfs, saying

> 'property target does not exist on type number'

The relevant version of jQuery is [1.7.2](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)

**EDIT**

Following the answer from @FunStuff, I have modified the code as follows:

```
.map( (i, el)=> {
  return $(el).val();
})
```

Which Resharper likes. I am still confused as to how that method signature resolved in Vanilla JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the first argument is the index and it's type is a **number**.

```
$("#id").map((index, element) => {
  console.log(element);
});
```

map(callback: (**index**: **number**, domElement: Element) => any): JQuery;

And watch that the second argument is the current DOM element not the event.

Now it should work.

Comment: That does work, see my edit which includes a second query.

Comment: I'm not sure that I really understand the second question. can you explain more please?

Comment: The original code (return $(ev.target).val();) must have worked with standard jQuery ( I assume) but how?

Comment: It does not work. I tested your code and it does not throw an error but your ev  is the index and your code returns undefined. This code just returns the jquery object   console.log($(0));

Comment: Its not my code, which is the problem I am guessing someone wrote it to a valid interface, and it did work, but its possible that it never did I suppose.